# PHP display line-to-line execution time

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm pretty sure this has never been asked before, which surprises me a little bit, but if it's a duplicate, please point at the right question :)

We have heavy lag on our servers and I started logging `microtime()` at various keypoints in our system, but it's still not precise enough and I would like to know the microtime for every single line of code. However this would be an IMMENSE piece of work to do + every file would be double the size + it would be pretty stupid.

So I'd like to know if anyone has any ideas how for example I would set a flag `?log_test=1` in the url for example (with security measures of course) and it would echo `microtime()` (or anything similar) after each line ending with a semicolon.

I realize this sounds ridiculous, but I'm just wondering if anyone has any ideas of capturing execution time as precise as possible without re-writing the code. We're using CodeIgniter by the way, in case it gives anyone ideas

Comment: *Use a profiler.* That's the tool you're looking for, something that *profiles* your code and gives you a breakdown of all timings.

Comment: Thanks @deceze! I used profilers in the past for Java, C++ and the Codigniter profiler, but I had no idea you there were run-time server-side profilers for PHP! XDebug sounds good actually, thanks again!!